# Dropping row when a value is missing by group in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I need to remove ids by grouping if an id has a missing value in any category row.

Here is a sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 cat = c("A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                 score = c(5,NA,7, 3,4,5))

> df
  id cat score
1  1   A     5
2  1   B    NA
3  1   C     7
4  2   A     3
5  2   B     4
6  2   C     5
```

I would like to remove `id=1` since it has at least one of the `cat` values missing. How can I get the desired dataset below.

```
   > df
      id cat score
      2   A     3
      2   B     4
      2   C     5
```

Comment: `df[!(df[,'id'] %in% (df[is.na(df$score),"id"])),]`

Answer (score 1):

## base R

```r
df[ave(df$score, df$id, FUN = anyNA) == 0L,]
#   id cat score
# 4  2   A     3
# 5  2   B     4
# 6  2   C     5
```

This works because `ave` does a calculation for all values within a group, and returns the (same-class) of the input, same-length, on the output. While `anyNA` returns `logical`, because `df$score` is numeric/integer, the output is coerced to that class. (It's not ideal/desirable, in my book, but it's the design and what we must deal with.)

```r
ave(df$score, df$id, FUN = anyNA)
# [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!anyNA(score)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#      id cat   score
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     2 A         3
# 2     2 B         4
# 3     2 C         5
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create a separate dataframe that lists all of the id's that contain missing data and then use that to filter out those id's in your main df dataframe.

```
id_with_missing_data <- df %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), is.na))
  
df <- df %>% 
  filter(!id %in% id_with_missing_data$id)
```